# HQL using parameters in where clause

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I'm currently trying to do a HQL query something like this:

```
["friend1", "friend2", "friend3"].each { friend ->
        Query q = sessionFactory.currentSession.createQuery(
                """select p.screenName, count(*) from Person p
                        where (p.:thisfriend.enemies = :true)
                        group by p.screenName""")
                .setParameter("thisfriend", friend)
```

(each person has 3 'friend positions', some of whom may be 'enemies') and it's obviously upset with the in-line parameterization of "thisfriend". Is there a way to be cunning here or do I need 3 separate queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use parameters for field names. Use string.format or criteria.